# Android - implement something like a Unix cronjob

Tags: android, web-services

I would like to perform a REST API request every X mins to update the database my application uses.

That should happen whether my application is running or not. That also means, if the user restarts their mobile, the polling should start straightaway, without the need to run the application first.

Basically I want to implement kind of this Unix cronjob

```
*/5 * * * * /usr/local/bin/update_something.sh
```

Is that possible via the Android Services? If so, can you please give me some basic directions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can use a service but a service needs to be triggered/started at some relevant point of time. You can try using classes like `AlarmManager` that can trigger your service every x mins.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

Edit-

To start your service at device boot you can use a broadcast receiver

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

Chk this link out

http://www.androidcompetencycenter.com/2009/06/start-service-at-boot/

Comment: Be aware that polling the network from the background at intervals less than 15 minutes without giving the user a setting to control the interval is generally considered rude and inconsiderate of the user's battery life. See the twitter app for an example of this sort of setting - the user is offered the choice to poll anywhere from every 5 minutes to every 4 hours. You should also favor using the inexact intervals offered by `AlarmManager` so that the system may wake your app along with others that have work to do around the same time.

Answer (score 1):

So, here is how I would do it:

1. Have a [`BroadcastReceiver`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) that listens to an acceptable broadcast `Intent`, such as [`Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED) (you will to declare a permission in your manifest in order to receive that intent)
2. When that `BroadcastReceiver` receives that intent, have it call an alarm-setting `Service` that will set up [`AlarmManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html).
3. In that Service, Set up AlarmManager so that it will send an Intent to the real  
   `Service every five minutes. (I don't know the details about how`AlarmManager` works)
4. You can stop that first service - your real Service will receive Intents sent by AlarmManager.

Answer (score 0):

[Android Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) would be the way to go.

Comment: The thing is an application needs to start the service explicitly, I reckon. I am afraid they can't start straight after a boot on the mobile.