# Android app starting on date?

Tags: java, android, cordova

I have phonegap app on android, and I am writing a plugin to schedule app start on specific date. How exactly can I do that? Lets say user choose one date tomorrow and when this date is reached app is started by itself, or it shows some alert message, what I want to achive with this is some scheduler or something like this.

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4297858/android-implement-something-like-a-unix-cronjob

Answer (score 1):

I think you can make use of Service and IBinder classes. When the user triggers a date, start the service in the background and displays messages using status notifications (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html)

Hope the undermentioned example will give you a kickstart.

http://android-er.blogspot.co.uk/2010/10/simple-example-of-alarm-service-using.html

Answer (score 0):

That is basically an alarm clock. check for code for that.

I dont know what exactly you want to create but maybe a widget that shows alarm and then starts the app accordingly would be nicer and easier on resources.